# How to change Longitude format in a Netcdf file in R?

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, netcdf, netcdf4, cdo-climate

I have a netcdf file with three dimensions (time, lon, lat):

3 dimensions:
time  Size:14610   *** is unlimited ***
time_origin: 31-DEC-1979:18:00:00
long_name: t
calendar: standard
units: hours since 1979-01-01 00:00:00
lat  Size:201
point_spacing: even
units: degrees_north
standard_name: latitude
long_name: latitude
lon  Size:641
point_spacing: even
units: degrees_east
standard_name: longitude
long_name: longitude

What is odd about it is that the longitude is stored from -80 to +80:

```
lon <- ncvar_get(nc_data,"lon")#[LonIdx]
head(lon)
-80.00 -79.75 -79.50 -79.25 -79.00 -78.75

tail(lon)
78.75 79.00 79.25 79.50 79.75 80.00

dim(lon)
641
```

I want to apply a lon/lat index for middle Europe using:

```
LonIdx <- c(which( nc_data$dim$lon$vals < -77.5) , which( nc_data$dim$lon$vals > 77.5) )
LatIdx <- which( nc_data$dim$lat$vals > 35 & nc_data$dim$lat$vals < 50)

lon <- ncvar_get(nc_data,"lon")[LonIdx]
nlon <- dim(lon)
head(lon)
-80.00 -79.75 -79.50 -79.25 -79.00 -78.75
tail(lon)
78.75 79.00 79.25 79.50 79.75 80.00
dim(lon)
[1] 20
```

so far so good, but when I want to plot it with a levelplot the result is messed up, I assume because the longitude is stored this way and not from 0-360 (degrees east)

```
grid <- expand.grid(lon=lon2, lat=lat2)

# Plots
# December, January, February
cutpts <- seq(
  min(dec_jan_feb_mat),round(max(dec_jan_feb_mat),1),length.out = 9)
plt1 <- levelplot(dec_jan_feb_mat ~ lon * lat, data=grid, at=cutpts, cuts=5, pretty=T, 
                  col.regions= c(brewer.pal(8,"YlGnBu")), margin=F,
                  main="1980-2019 (December, January, February) - Precipitation mean", xlab = "longitude", 
                  ylab = "latitude")
DJF_plot_precip <- plt1 + latticeExtra::layer(sp.lines(countries, col="black", 
                                                lwd=1.0))
DJF_plot_precip
```

How do I transform the longitude accordingly so that I can plot my results?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

as you added the `cdo-climate` tag, I'm presuming you are happy with a `cdo` command to preprocess the file to 0-360 from -180 to 180.  If so, the following would do the trick:

```
cdo sellonlatbox,0,360,-90,90 in.nc out.nc
```

[See this post for alternatives answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57682977/converting-longitude-in-netcdf-from-0360-to-180180-using-nco/)

Comment: Thank you Adrian. Do you have an idea on how to do it in R?

Comment: you can try this? https://github.com/markpayneatwork/ClimateOperators